# Elliptic Curve Point Arithmetic in Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++, elliptic-curve

```
#include "include/cryptopp/oids.h"
#include "include/cryptopp/eccrypto.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using namespace CryptoPP;

void init()
{
    ECDH<ECP>::Domain ecdhc(ASN1::secp256k1());
    auto g_p = ecdhc.GetGroupParameters();
    auto g_ec = g_p.GetSubgroupGenerator();
    auto g_ec_ = g_p.GetCurve().Subtract(g_p.GetCurve().Add(g_ec, g_ec), g_ec);

    if(g_p.GetCurve().Equal(g_ec_, g_ec))
        printf("P\n");
    else
        printf("NP\n");
}

int main()
{
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

As an example code above.

It's expected to perform the following arithmetic:

```
g_ec_ = (g_ec + g_ec) - g_ec
```

So `g_ec` and `g_ec_` should be the same.

But the code output `False`. Can someone explain it?

Comment: You're right, that arithmetic should hold true. I wonder if the `GetCurve.Equal()` call isn't for comparing points? I can't see it in the docs because the docs are shit.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `Equal`. The coordinates of the points can be printed with `g_ec_.x` / `g_ec_.y`. I compared the coordinates with the results given by ECPy. For ECPy, the computation gives the expected result, i.e. P+P-P == P. But the the ECPy coordinates already differ from the cryptopp coordinates after the first addition, i.e. the coordinates for P+P are different. So there seems to be a more general problem than just the `Equal` function.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 interesting... I wonder if this is an issue with the library, ofc the points should be the same if the curve geometry and curve arithmetic is implemented correctly.

Comment: Yeah I'm also suspecting there might be some issue with ECC in crypto++, also in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441187/cryptopped25519verifier-shows-different-result-from-libsignal).

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in the 8.4 release ([reference](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/994)).