# CryptoPP::ed25519::Verifier shows different result from libsignal

Tags: c++, crypto++, ed25519, curve-25519

I'm trying to implement **curve25519 verification** with CryptoPP. I tried the `libsignal` library first, witch shows correct result. Then I tried the same data with CryptoPP, but shows wrong result.

Here is the code using `libsignal` to verify a signature:

```
string pub = str2hex("0504f05568cc7a16fa9b4bc1c9d9294a80b7727e349365f855031a180bf0f80910");
ec_public_key* pub_key;
curve_decode_point(&pub_key, (uint8_t*)pub.data(), pub.size(), 0);

string message = str2hex("05f1fd491d63f1860bdaf3f9b0eb46c2494b7f184a32d9e6c859a421ad284f4307");
string signature = str2hex("5e525df3360ea62281efe8fb9e183521105bb3d9ba8ad43be9fac9d87dd216a6ea9e64099f6f05fbcd6e5a39ab239aad8c1e03d27a1378e4bcbf8937eac4300a");

int ret = curve_verify_signature(
    pub_key, 
    (uint8_t*)message.data(), message.size(), 
    (uint8_t*)signature.data(), signature.size()
    );

cout << "ret: " << ret << endl; // shows 1 (correct)
```

The result is 1 which means corrent. Please note `libsignal` requires the `pub_key` begin with a byte 0x05(key-type), not for `CryptoPP` here.

The code using `CryptoPP`:

```
string pub = str2hex("04f05568cc7a16fa9b4bc1c9d9294a80b7727e349365f855031a180bf0f80910");

string message = str2hex("05f1fd491d63f1860bdaf3f9b0eb46c2494b7f184a32d9e6c859a421ad284f4307");
string signature = str2hex("5e525df3360ea62281efe8fb9e183521105bb3d9ba8ad43be9fac9d87dd216a6ea9e64099f6f05fbcd6e5a39ab239aad8c1e03d27a1378e4bcbf8937eac4300a");

ed25519::Verifier verifier((uint8_t*)pub.data());
bool ret = verifier.VerifyMessage(
    (uint8_t*)message.data(), message.size(), 
    (uint8_t*)signature.data(), signature.size()
    );
cout << "ret: " << ret << endl; // shows 0 (wrong)
```

It shows 0, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Which crypto++ version is this? My understanding is that the recently released 8.3 fixed some ECC-related bugs ([link](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/869), [link](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/878)), but possibly not all, unfortunately ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65290544/elliptic-curve-point-arithmetic-in-crypto)).

Comment: It's version 8.3, `#define CRYPTOPP_VERSION 830`

Answer (score 0):

libsignal has a customized implementation on curve25519_verification:

- curve25519 public key is converted to ed25519 public key (see [here](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c/blob/master/src/curve25519/ed25519/additions/curve_sigs.c#L62))
- the verification is done using ed25519 signature verification algorithm (see [here](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c/blob/master/src/curve25519/ed25519/additions/curve_sigs.c#L84))

If you try to verify the signature using the converted ed25519 public key with CryptoPP, the verification would fail. That's because the [sign](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c/blob/master/src/curve25519/ed25519/additions/curve_sigs.c#L8) and [edd25519_verify](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c/blob/master/src/curve25519/ed25519/additions/open_modified.c#L9) operations are also slightly adjusted in libsignal.